# two instances of tinymce mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

TinyMCE View Template

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            //elements: "engRichMCE,araRichMCE",
            elements: "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",
            theme: "simple",
            height: "300",
            width: "400",
            verify_html: false,
            theme_simple_resizing: true,
            content_css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")",
            convert_urls: false
        })
    })();
</script>

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

Model

```
 [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed"), AllowHtml]
 public string eng_html { get; set; }

 [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed"), AllowHtml]
 public string ara_html { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.eng_html, new { id = "engRichMCE" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eng_html)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ara_html, new { id = "araRichMCE" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ara_html)
```

The Problem is only one instance of tinyMCE is loading in my view, i need both fields to get tinyMCE editor, any advice ?

**Update**
What i've done so far, looking at tinyMCE documentations,
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:mode
mode value can be exact, textareas or specific_textareas. If set `mode="textarea"` in the init function, all textareas are converted to tinMCE...which is not what i need.

Also duplicating the partial view that holds the tinyMCE didn't work.

using `mode="exact"` and `elements="araRichMCE,engRichMCE"` in tinyMCE init function and adding IDs in my view  did not work either ?

Comment: Load this site in Chrome or Firefox and check the Console; there are probably some JavaScript errors.

Comment: JS Error: 'TypeError: q is not a constructor'

Comment: And if you work through the JavaScript for `tinymce` you'll find some context for that error I'm guessing. For me personally to help you're going to have to get me a lot more context about that error. Some others here may know the JS for that control better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Upadated Package TinyMCE downloaded latest 4.0.11

in my model deleted this

```
[UIHint("tinymce_simple"), AllowHtml]
```

and kept

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
```

**in my edit view page edit.view**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            tinyMCE.init({
                selector: "textarea#eng_html,textarea#ara_html",
                content_css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")",
            })
        })();
    </script>
```

in the view my two html containg textareas will be selected by tinyMCE

Thank you all