# Issue with multiple RichTextBox in same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, richtextbox, tinymce-4

I am currently facing an issue with Richtextbox in one of my asp.net mvc application. I have two richtextbox one on the main page and other in the modal popup.

I have used TinyMCE.

I am always getting one Richtextbox instead of two, other always comes a normal textarea.

Below is the code

```
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.SignificantOrders.OrderSummary)
```

for normal richtextbox

```
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.SignificantOrders.EditOrderSummary)
```

for modal pop rich text box.

The solutions I tried:
1. Tried whether it is the issue with the popup, found it is not an issue with a popup as If I comment main page richtextbox popup shows the richtextbox.

2. Found the `id` of both the richtextbox are same. For that I made change in
   tinymce_full.cshtml
   Replaced this
    elements: `"@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)"`,
   with
   elements: `"@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)"`,
   but still only one richtextbox comes

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: That code cannot possibly generate the same `id` attributes - they will be `id="SignificantOrders_OrderSummary"` and `id="SignificantOrders_EditOrderSummary"` respectively

Comment: Tried this one? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146044/two-instances-of-tinymce-mvc-c-sharp

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, earlier it was giving same id then I changed my code to "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)" now I am getting different Ids but only one richtextbox is coming

Comment: Just delete the `@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)` code - its pointless. And we cannot guess what your code is in the `tinymce_full.cshtml` template is, or how you have attached the plugin